# Why have Amp-Sticky-Ad additional V1.0 JS Library?

Tags: amp-html

The curent version for [AMP Sticky AD](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/extensions/amp-sticky-ad) is:

> https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sticky-ad-1.0.js

There is a additional Version

> https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sticky-ad-0.1.js

All other Component (that I use) have only Version 0.1
What is the different between 0.1 and 1.0 and why have sticky Ad both?
The Validator says to both Version valid.

Comment: I think if you're looking for update changes, check out the [Update doc for amp-sticky-ad 1.0](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/commit/8b8934944235e08cb99ca01830a807e24b960293) notes. That way you can compare the recent improvements to the last version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/6169).
The main changes are UX issues.